# How to load react components to phantomjs?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, testing, phantomjs, automated-tests

I create a Selenium Client:

```
var client = webdriverio.remote({
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'phantomjs'
  }
});
```

But when I try to get any selector from my React app, it says:

```
Error: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters (".active-tab").
```

I realize I should use `react-addons-test-utils`, but how to connect them in test?

```
describe('test React components', function(){
  before(function(){
    return client.init().url('http://localhost:8080/');
  });

  it('works as expected', () = > {
    return client
      .waitForVisible('.active-tab')
      .getText('.active-tab')
      .then(function(res, err) {
        return res.should.equal('Opened Tab!');
      });
  });

  after(function() {
    return client.end();
  });
});
```

It's not working. I get an error:

```
Error: element (.active-tab) still not visible after 500ms
```

I assume it's because I don't load React app to the PhantomJS DOM.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @risto-novik, hi, I sew you have big expirience in Reactjs+Phantomjs. Could you please help me to connect them? Thank you in advance!